# ConnectFour Program Issues in Java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, matrix

I'm creating a Connect Four program from scratch for good practice and I am having trouble with my checkAlignment() method, or what would be the win condition. It works in some rows but not all, and it doesn't work for any other direction (vertically, diagonally forwards, diagonally backwards).

```
public char checkAlignment(int row, int column) {
char color = board[row][column];
char[][] current = getBoard();

// Horizontal Left-to-Right Check - - - - - - - - - -
if (column + 4 <= columns) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (current[row][column + i] != color) {
            return NONE;
        }
    }
    return color;
}

// Horizontal Right-To-Left Check - - - - - - - -
if (column - 4 > -1) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (current[row][column - i] != color) {
            return NONE;
        }
    }
    return color;
}

//  Vertical Top-To-Bottom Check - - - - - - -
if (row + 4 <= rows) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (current[row + i][column] != color) {
            return NONE;
        }
    }
    return color;
}

// Vertical Bottom-To-Top Check - - - - - - - -
if (row - 4 > -1) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (current[row - i][column] != color) {
            return NONE;
        }
    }
    return color;
}

// Main Diagonal Backwards Check - - - - - - - - - -
if (column - 4 > -1 && row - 4 > -1) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
            if (current[row - i][column - j] != color) {
                return NONE;
            }
        }
    }
    return color;
}

// Main Diagonal Forwards Check - - - - - - - - - -
if (column + 4 <= columns && row + 4 <= rows) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
            if (current[row + i][column + j] != color) {
                return NONE;
            }
        }
    }
    return color;
}

// Secondary Diagonal Backwards Check - - - - - - - - -
if (column - 4 > -1 && row + 4 <= rows) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
            if (current[row + i][column - j] != color) {
                return NONE;
            }
        }
    }
    return color;
}
// Secondary Diagonal Forwards Check - - - - - - - - - -
if (column + 4 <= columns && row - 4 > -1) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
            if (current[row - i][column + j] != color) {
                return NONE;
            }
        }
    }
    return color;
}
return NONE;
```

}

Can anyone help me out?

EDITED/ADJUSTED:

```
public char checkAlignment(int row, int column) {
    char color = board[row][column];
    char[][] current = getBoard();

    // Horizontal Left-to-Right Check
    if (column + 4 <= NUM_COLS) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (current[row][column + i] != color) {
                return NONE;
            }
        }
        return color;
    }

    // Horizontal Right-To-Left Check
    if (column - 4 > -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (current[row][column - i] != color) {
                return NONE;
            }
        }
        return color;
    }

    //  Vertical Top-To-Bottom Check
    if (row + 4 <= NUM_ROWS) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (current[row + i][column] != color) {
                return NONE;
            }
        }
        return color;
    }

    // Vertical Bottom-To-Top Check
    if (row - 4 > -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (current[row - i][column] != color) {
                return NONE;
            }
        }
        return color;
    }

    // Main Diagonal Backwards Check
    if (column - 4 > -1 && row - 4 > -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (current[row - i][column - j] != color) {
                    return NONE;
                }
            }
        }
        return color;
    }

    // Main Diagonal Forwards Check - - - - - - - - - -
    if (column + 4 <= NUM_COLS && row + 4 <= NUM_ROWS) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (current[row + i][column + j] != color) {
                    return NONE;
                }
            }
        }
        return color;
    }

    // Secondary Diagonal Backwards Check - - - - - - - - -
    if (column - 4 > -1 && row + 4 <= NUM_ROWS) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (current[row + i][column - j] != color) {
                    return NONE;
                }
            }
        }
        return color;
    }
    // Secondary Diagonal Forwards Check - - - - - - - - - -
    if (column + 4 <= NUM_COLS && row - 4 > -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (current[row - i][column + j] != color) {
                    return NONE;
                }
            }
        }
        return color;
    }
    return NONE;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it every one of your loops use `i=1` and then go upto 4, running four times each. However your row and column is always checked with that +/- 4 away from the `current`. If I am reading this correctly, you are checking one more than you need to in some cases. So either make i=0 or go upto 3 (as you already checked your own square with current).

*Edit: I gave this a second look*

My first statement above was not really a problem. The real problem I think is that for each item you are checking only 4 in a single direction away from the 'current' one. This is not always true as shown in the following example where 'y' is last piece put into the grid.

```
x x y x
```

So In this case you can try the following code that checks the total number left and right of the 'current' selected token. If there is 4 or more in both directions togeather its a connect-4:

```
//Horizantal check
//Right side
int connected = 0;
int i = 1;
while (column + i <= columns) {
    if (current[row + i][column] != color) {
        break;
    }else{
        connected++;
    }
    i++;
}   
i = 1;
//left side
while (column - i <= columns) {
    if (current[row - i][column] != color) {
        break;
    }else{
        connected++;
    }
    i++;
}
if(connected >= 4){//total connected
    return color;
}else{
    return NONE;
}
```

On review your vertical plain check looks fine. Recall that in connect-4 you drop tokens down the grid so you can never drop a new token into a slot that has another token above it (on the turn you dropped it) meaning that doing the vertical check upwards is not necessary.

```
//Vertical plain check - The one dropped must always be on top
if (row - 4 > -1) {
    for(int i=1; i<4;i++){
        if (current[row - i][column] != color) {
            return NONE;
        }
    }
    return color;
}
```

Hopefully this helps somewhat in getting these two directions correct. For diagonals you will need to do something like I have for the horizontal plain.

Comment: I'll try that out. Would I change "j = 1" to "j = 0" as well?

Comment: Yes you would need to as well.

Comment: I have added the adjusted/edited version now. How does it look?

Comment: I updated my answer, hopefully provideing some extra help steve-smith